# How to get normal (classic) toolbars in Office 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I don't have MS Office 2007 installed, but have this question:
The most obvious change in Office 2007 is the new "ribbon" interface that has replaced the classic "menu+toolbar" interface.

**--> Is there a setting to get the classic look in Office 2007**, or is it gone for good?

Comment: I'd advise you to just start using new toolbar :] You'll get used to it very quickly and will find it as convenient as the old one was. Or maybe even better.

Comment: I'd already be much happier if the new toolbar would not automatically change its active tab. If I select a tab on that ribbon, why does Office insist to show another tab when I click in the text somewhere?

Comment: I like the ribbon, except from the part that you can't customize the contents of the standard ribbons. If you want some additional buttons in there, you have to create you own custom tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google showed me [this blog post](http://thepaisano.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/replacing-the-office-2007-ribbon-bar/), have not tried it myself though.

Comment: I've chosen this answer because it appears to solve the issue without any additional software. The comments about learning the new style are good too!

Answer (score 12):

No. The new ribbon interface (fluent UI) is the only available menu style in office 2007. **There is no official option to switch to the classic menu bars.**

(There are 3rd party apps and custom hacks that you could use to build up menus that looked like the old ones in the Ribbon - see [tnorthcutt's](https://superuser.com/questions/41628/how-to-get-normal-classic-toolbars-in-office-2007/41632#41632) answer)

If you want my honest advice though, don't try and force it back to how it was. Just take the time to learn the new interface. When it comes right down to it, it's just a slightly different button placement, you'll get used to it surprisingly quickly. There is no real reason to hang onto the past, embrace the change for what it is and work with it. Every time some new software comes out that changes something people moan about it for a while, not because it's actually worse but just because it's different. Different isn't a good reason to moan. Try it out. when you've tried it out for a few months and learnt where the common buttons are, if you then have a genuine reason to dislike it, then you can change.

Comment: There are no official options to get the classic menus.

Comment: @alex: Very true. I've edited to clarify that point.

Comment: I love the new style personally. I so wish Visual Studios move to this model.  I never use the toolbar there specifically cause it never has anything I need.

Answer (score 2):

[FREE STUFF]

This is the ultimate solution ive found after weeks of search...

[Ubit Menu - Ofiice 2007](http://www.ubit.ch/software/ubitmenu-office2007/)

[Link Translated from German to English](http://translate.google.com.au/translate?prev=hp&hl=en&js=y&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubit.ch%2Fsoftware%2Fubitmenu-office2007%2F&sl=de&tl=en&history_state0=)

I mean ive used few, tried few... but this one is the BEST

Comment: Even though I'm mostly used to the Office 2007 / 2010 interface, there are times when (1) I am in a hurry and (2) I cannot remember where the function is in the new interface. At those times, the Ubit menu is a lifesaver! It has also saved the sanity of several clients who ended up "stuck" with Office 2007. FWIW, the tweaks to the new UI in Office 2010 make it a much easier transition from 2003.

Answer (score 1):

**[RibbonCustomizer™](http://pschmid.net/office2007/ribboncustomizer/starter.php)** is an add-in for Microsoft® Access™, Excel®, Outlook®, PowerPoint® and Word 2007. It allows you to customize the Ribbon User Interface with only a few mouse clicks! Microsoft did not include that ability in Office 2007, but with this add-in you are no longer stuck with a static User Interface!

Features:

> Customize Ribbon dialog
>
> Add groups to tabs
>
> Reset the ribbon
>
> Reset a tab
>
> **Classic UI tabs for Excel, PowerPoint and Word 2007**
>
> Load pre-defined RIBX packages
>   Quickly switch multiple customizations
>   on and off

License: RibbonCustomizer™ Starter Edition is free

**[UBitMenu](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/UBitMenu.shtml)** was designed to be a simple way for professional Microsoft Office users to get accustomed to the new ribbon based interface of Office 2007 without any performance loss. It will emulate / activate the Office 2003 menu in Word 2007, Excel 2007 and Powerpoint 2007.

[image]

License: Freeware

Answer (score 0):

There do appear to be programs you can install to get this functionality.  [Classic Menu for Office 2007](http://download.cnet.com/Classic-Menu-for-Office-2007/3000-18483_4-10637184.html) is one, and although not free, does have a free trial period.

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon view is the default for Office 2007.  Using XML code, you can customize the ribbon or re-create the classic menus.  That is what the program tnorthcutt does.